# How do Electrum/Sparrow/Caravan generate multisig addresses?

Tags: electrum, multi-signature, address-generation

I'm trying to "manually" confirm the Bitcoin addresses that Electrum, Sparrow, and Caravan generate from a deterministic multisig addresses.

As an example, I have the following 2-of-2 wallet:

Seed words #1:

```
legal thumb play interest flash will lucky jar outdoor guard vendor found crucial develop spring valley example supply fortune pole right acid alert page
```

Seed words #2:

```
begin siege speak boat before mad solve dance lawsuit point machine cake tragic fiber waste equip loan syrup cloud credit shock choose chest finish
```

Using [Ian Coleman's BIP39 Tool](https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39), I can confirm the Master Public Key (xpub) with the following steps:

1. Enter the seed words under **BIP39 Mnemonic**
2. Under **Derivation Path**, Select the **BIP32** tab
3. Under **BIP32 Derivation Path**, enter `m/45'/0` (for legacy multisig)
4. Copy the **BIP32 Extended Public Key**

The resulting xpub matches with what Electrum generates when entering those seed words as a 2-of-2 legacy multisig wallet. The example xpub's are:

Wallet #1 xpub:

```
xpub6B7nJf6xmWPjeVpdSwePjDmUJxRWSVf3vXu47AYKiLTyW7rPUyysKVU8TtRJ9VXtAVNHjx6EsueiE9Mw7JyP4dVhZjJF4ViVAJNaoZo49uw
```

Wallet #2 xpub:

```
xpub6Ab52xTpcFNYToaXBT6opdaqo18rKSYA3rnum4XuE8pLW9N748QJq1PP5z93KSfbpfMVRLqsYgZYwfNmzomqkw4kvopD1PuXS4DuNaY4ZBi
```

The first address in this multisig wallet is `3BWrS4WXB61sppUN7zxgAqxzjcSvML7jWC`. When I enter those xpubs into [Sparrow Bitcoin Wallet](https://www.sparrowwallet.com/) (with **Script Type** `Legacy (P2SH)` and **Derivation** `m/45'`) I get the same address. [Caravan](https://unchained-capital.github.io/caravan/#/wallet) also gives the same address.

My question is this: *how do I "manually" generate that first Bitcoin address*?

I've tried using [Ian Coleman's Multisig Tool](https://iancoleman.io/multisig/), [Bitcore](https://bitpay.github.io/bitcore-playground/app/#/multisig), [coinbin Bitcoin Wallet](https://coinb.in/#newMultiSig), and [the addmultisigaddress command from Bitcoin core](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/addmultisigaddress.html). They all require "Public Keys" of the addresses from the two wallets. Where can I find/generate those Public Keys (preferably using some sort of browser-html or command line tool)? I've tried using the Public Key's generated at the bottom of the **BIP39 Tool** from above, but no combination of those keys in any of the tools results in the same generated address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full derivation path appears to follow [BIP 45](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0045.mediawiki), but not quite exactly. The actual public keys are being generated from the xpub at the path `m/45'/0/0`. For the  first address, the derivation paths for the public keys will be `m/45'/0/0/0`. You can get these pubkeys using Ian Coleman's BIP 39 tool by going to the BIP 32 tab and entering `m/45'/0/0` as the derivation path. Then scroll down to the derived addresses and select the first one.

You should see that the first pubkey from the first mnemonic is `03ae50de983900d2898d975cd71c8520c88da868acc434e259775ee58b5e4ce311` and the first pubkey from the second mnemonic is `03c2367af137659943c11ee02aa88ec9b2ca5b424183b8d3a6990db1907bc475ae`. If you enter these into any multisig generating tool, you should get the address you are expecting.

For example, Bitcoin Core's `createmultisig`:

```
$ bitcoin-cli createmultisig 2 '["03ae50de983900d2898d975cd71c8520c88da868acc434e259775ee58b5e4ce311","03c2367af137659943c11ee02aa88ec9b2ca5b424183b8d3a6990db1907bc475ae"]'
{
  "address": "3BWrS4WXB61sppUN7zxgAqxzjcSvML7jWC",
  "redeemScript": "522103ae50de983900d2898d975cd71c8520c88da868acc434e259775ee58b5e4ce3112103c2367af137659943c11ee02aa88ec9b2ca5b424183b8d3a6990db1907bc475ae52ae",
  "descriptor": "sh(multi(2,03ae50de983900d2898d975cd71c8520c88da868acc434e259775ee58b5e4ce311,03c2367af137659943c11ee02aa88ec9b2ca5b424183b8d3a6990db1907bc475ae))#eq5t5j72"
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Setting the derivation path to `m/45'/0/0` generated the public keys that match the address generated from Electrum, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are making multisig addresses, so the first thing to change is to select BIP141 not BIP32 tab.

Under BIP141, go to script semantics drop down menu. Select P2WSH 1-1 multisig.

Then manually adjust the derivation path just above.

You'll get 1 of 1 msig addresses below.

Use the Zpub give and enter into Electrum to generate a 1 of 1 msig wallet - not sure if Electrum allows a 1 of 1 msig wallet.

If not, you need to make 2 keys with Ian Coleman (that's one way of many), extract 2 Zpubs, ignore the addresses, make a 2 of 2 Electrum wallet with those Zpubs, print the addresses, make a duplicate wallet with those Zpubs using Sparrow or Specter, and finally compare the address list is identical to Electrum's.